# How to get the innerHTML of an input in Java script

Tags: javascript

I am making a TODO list. I have difficulties with setting the input text on my card. Everything I write in the input, I want to select and to put on the card.

I tried to select the `innerHTML` of an `input` when I type something in. I don't know how to select the typed input text. I would then create a new element with the text inside, and would append it to the card.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.add');
let textspace = document.querySelector('.todotext');

const input = document.querySelector('input');

// eventlistner by button clicked

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('input').innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="todoheader">TODO List</div>
  <div class="todotext"></div>
  <ul class="list"></ul>
  <div class="addtodo">
    <buton class="add" type="button"> + </buton>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="add todo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assign the unique id to your input field and use `document.getElementById('uniqueID').value` instead `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `getElementsByClassName` will return [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is array-like, you need to use `querySelector` instead, also the `innerHTML`, `textContent`, `innerText` properties all are empty string for the `input` because the input is a self-closing tag without content inside, you need to use `value` property.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.add');
let textspace = document.querySelector('.todotext');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

// eventlistner by button clicked

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var txt = input.value;
  console.log(txt)
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="todoheader">TODO List</div>
  <div class="todotext"></div>
  <ul class="list"></ul>
  <div class="addtodo">
    <buton class="add" type="button"> + </buton>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="add todo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the `input` use the `value` property, not `innerHTML`. Also note that you already have a reference to the `input` Element in the `input` variable, so you don't need to use `getElementsByClassName()` to retrieve it - not least of all because the syntax there is flawed.

Once you have the text you can use `createElement()` to add a new `p` element to the `.todotext` container:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.add');
const textspace = document.querySelector('.todotext');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const txt = input.value;  
  if (!txt)
    return;
  
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = txt;
  textspace.appendChild(p);
  input.value = '';
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="todoheader">TODO List</div>
  <div class="todotext"></div>
  <ul class="list"></ul>
  <div class="addtodo">
    <button class="add" type="button"> + </button>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="add todo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already answered your question. I just wanted to point out that there is a misspelling in your code (buton instead of button). Fix that and the button element would be rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('input').value;

You should get the value of an input , not the innerHTML

Also assign a unique id to you input fields and select them with it, it's much better :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var txt = document.getElementByClassName('input').value;
});
```

You were using `getElementByClassName` which will be HTMLCollection.To loop over each element you need to convert it into an array loop over them.